# Do depleted uranium shells cause birth defects?

Tags: radiation, war, birth

I've seen [a few](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/health-news/iraq-records-huge-rise-in-birth-defects-8210444.html) [articles](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2010/dec/30/faulluja-birth-defects-iraq) on depleted uranium rounds possibly causing birth defects in the last few years, but most of the articles have a 'doubter'.  From what I can tell, the numbers aren't conclusive.

[This environmental health site's paper](http://www.ehjournal.net/content/4/1/17) seems to suggest it's a real thing, but I don't know how much to trust the site.

Would someone with better science and google-fu be able to shed some light on this please?

Comment: Environmental Health seen to be a good link, searching around let me find many very contradictory articles, with political coloring. WHO seems to see no risk, most other found articles found an evidence, but are possibly not reliable.
http://www.who.int/mip2001/files/2374/HealthinEmergencies,IssueNo.9.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that wikipedia pretty much answer the question.

**There are some controversies, but it seems that the majority of the studies points toward a correlation between exposure to DU and the risk of birth defects in children.**

[Depleted uranium - Gulf War syndrome and soldier complaints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depleted_uranium#Gulf_War_syndrome_and_soldier_complaints)

> Human epidemiological evidence is consistent with increased risk of
> birth defects in the offspring of persons exposed to DU.[10] A 2001
> study of 15,000 February 1991 U.S. Gulf War combat veterans and 15,000
> control veterans found that the Gulf War veterans were 1.8 (fathers)
> to 2.8 (mothers) times more likely to have children with birth
> defects.[97] After examination of children's medical records two years
> later, the birth defect rate increased by more than 20%

Anyway, I would like to point out that the primary hazard is chemical and not radioactive (from the same page)

> The primary radiation danger from depleted uranium is due to alpha
> particles, which do not travel far through air, and do not penetrate
> clothing. Thus, the primary concern is internal exposure, due to
> inhalation, ingestion or shrapnel contamination. Available evidence
> suggests that this risk is small relative to the chemical hazard

and

[Environmental and Workplace Health : Depleted Uranium](http://www.hc-sc.gc.ca/ewh-semt/pubs/radiation/uranium-eng.php)

> Insoluble depleted uranium is considered the most hazardous form for
> inhalation as it remains in the lungs. A dose of 1 millisievert would
> be received from inhaling 8 milligrams of insoluble depleted uranium.
>
> Soluble depleted uranium is the most hazardous form for ingestion as
> it is absorbed into the body. A dose of 1 millisievert would be
> received from ingesting about 1400 milligrams of soluble depleted
> uranium. This route of exposure presents only a small fraction of the
> potential radiological risk of inhalation for the same amount of
> intake. The relative radiological risks for ingestion and inhalation
> are 1:200, if the depleted uranium contains equal amounts of soluble
> and insoluble forms.
>
> External exposure to depleted uranium presents
> the least hazard. A person could be completely surrounded by depleted
> uranium 24 hours a day for a week before receiving a 1 millisievert
> dose.

Comment: Did they rule our factors OTHER than DU as far as the first quote?

Comment: @Duralumin I think, with the current evidence, this is the best answer I can hope for.  The wikipedia article seems to be well referenced and seems to concur with most other articles/papers.  I'll leave it open for a little while longer for discussion, but I'll most likely be marking this answer as correct.

Comment: @DVK not just other factors, but placebo effect. Go hunting for something and suddenly you find a lot of it. Well known effect. Start an "awareness campaign" for something and the number of diagnoses (and especially self-diagnoses) skyrockets. Soon as the campaign ends the flood of diagnoses ends.

Comment: There were lots and lots of chemicals used in the Gulf war. Is there any study which compares Gulf War vets exposed to DU with Gulf War vets who weren't? (Although maybe all Gulf War vets were exposed, in which case you couldn't do such a study.)

Answer (score 5):

I would expect so, but not from a radiological standpoint. Depleted uranium is a heavy metal, like lead and mercury, and so I would expect similar toxic effects.

We are well aware of the dangers lead and mercury pose with regards to birth defects, and we also know uranium is very similar to lead chemically.

Doing a bit of searching, seems most studies focus in on the radiological effects, but I did find http://hps.org/publicinformation/ate/q746.html which concludes confirming my expectations: **uranium is about as dangerous as lead.**

Comment: Downvoted for poor answer. Depleted uranium is a little more dangerous than lead or even unenriched uranium. For one it's radioactive...

Comment: Dangerous and radioactive are not synonymous.  [Bananas and brazil nuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_equivalent_dose)  are radioactive.  [Granite countertops](http://www.epa.gov/rpdweb00/tenorm/granite-countertops.html) are radioactive.  Depleted uranium may well be more dangerous than lead due to radiation, but you'll need some numbers to back up that claim credibly.

Comment: @Coomie: considering I said "not from a radiological standpoint", I'd say that I'm aware of its radioactivity. It's just that its radioactivity is insignificant.

Comment: The starting question references a paper written in 2005 that's published in a decent peer reviewed journal. I don't understand how an opinion written in 2001 that comes with a disclaimer saying " The information and material posted on this website is intended as general reference information only. Specific facts and circumstances may alter the concepts and applications of materials and information described herein." should induce doubt in the 2005 paper.

Comment: @Coomie: Depleted uranium shouldn't be any more radioactive than untreated uranium. Do you have any evidence for this statement?

Comment: @Coomie - DU is dangerous more because of the toxicity of the metal, chemically, than radioactivity.  This answer is very correct about that, and the reference to lead and mercury is not dismissing the danger, but citing other examples of toxic, dangerous heavy metals.  The downvote is not one based on an informed viewpoint.

Answer (score -1):

There was a [documentary on public german TV](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERmabAyg4X0) on this specific subject, given the footage and claims in there that'd be a clear yes, depending on the level exposure to radiation. In the film, the film maker visits a physician in Basra, Iraq, who clearly confirms this hypothesis from his empirical perspective.

If you happen to come across such a used shell, pick it up and bring it to Germany, [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERmabAyg4X0#14m03s) will happen. You will get charged with a felony for setting free radiation. *Notable fact:* The (otherwise renowned) film-maker went to court to get the documentary broadcasted on the public TV channel that had initially ordered it and won. It then was broadcasted only once, very late at night.

Don't wanna sound like a conspiracy-nut, but the effort displayed here to keep this issue out of the average citizen's awareness is a clear indicator it's no good at all. Thus, i find it conclusive you're having a hard time getting your hands on some hard facts and/or research on this specific issue.

Comment: Could you put some quotes from your links in the answer?